# What is "Buttered Sugar"?

Tags: sugar

What is "Buttered Sugar"? Is it something specific?

I got the term from this image floating around the net. I'm trying to understand what specifically the different sugars are.

[image]

Comment: About a third of those aren't sugar, they're things that happen to contain a high concentration of one or more sugars -- or in at least one case, is a flavoring that happens to taste somewhat like sugar

Comment: Do you know if this is supposed to be a list of ingredients (e.g. off the side of a package)?

Comment: @Erica Yes. These are all supposed to be the sugar content listed in packaged food as ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

A search of the internet for "buttered sugar" comes up exclusively with variations of the this list on various websites that list alternative names for sugar. 
Of these only one ["Returning to nature"](http://www.returning2nature.com/index.php/component/k2/item/236-sugar-the-most-addictive-legal-substance-available-today) lists it as a synonymy for buttercream.

It is possible that site is correct and "buttered sugar" is a possibly rarely used alternate name for buttercream. I would suspect that it is more likely that there has been an error at some point in the past that has been copied between these sites.

Comment: That site says "found in cookies, icing, frosting, etc" when buttercream really *is* an icing/frosting. I guess you might still see it listed on ingredient labels, as one of the components of baked goods, but surely it would have a parenthetical list of the actual component ingredients, which would then include some kind of sugar.

Answer (score -1):

Basically melted butter mixed with sugar. I've think of this two ways: 1) spread butter over the toast and then sprinkle sugar over. 2) in baking context we usually mix the soft butter with sugar into this mixture before adding other ingredients. This is also called creaming.

Comment: I have never heard of the result of creaming being called "buttered sugar"